# Nested sequence of compact subsets covering an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to prove the following result:

There exists a sequence of compact sets $\{D_i\}$ with the following properties:

(a) Each $D_i$ is a subset of $A$.

(b) $D_i \subset Int(D_{i+1}) \ \forall i$, where $Int()$ denotes interior.

(c) $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i = A$.

(This result is used without proof in Lemma 16.2 of "Analysis on Manifolds" by James Munkres.)

Constructing a sequence with the first 2 properties is easy. We start with an arbitrary compact set $D_1 \subset A$ with non-empty interior (e.g. a closed ball centered at some point of A). We then use the following fact: every compact set contained inside an open set $A$ can be enclosed in the interior of another compact set contained inside $A$. This allows us to construct a sequence $\{D_i\}$ satisfying (a) and (b). However I don't know how to ensure that their union is $A$.

Comment: We can write $A$ as a countable union of open balls. Can you see what to do from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take$$D_n=\left\{a\in A\,\middle|\,\|a\|\leqslant n\wedge d(a,\partial A)\geqslant\frac1n\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

The author proved the following stronger lemma on p.122 in Section 15 in this book:

> **Lemma 15.1.** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a sequence $C_1,C_2,\dots$ of compact rectifiable subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$, such that $C_N\subset\operatorname{Int}C_{N+1}$ for each $N$.